# Не подключается JS файл на сайт Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Делают сайт на Django, понадобилось подключить JQuery, но не задача в том, что в консоле браузера выдает ошибку.

Вот так подключаю JQuery + JS файл

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 
<script src="{% static 'js/scripts.js' %}"></script>
```

Еще есть вот такая настройка на JS,она нужна чтобы работали табы на странице товара

```
 <script async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es-module-shims@1/dist/es-module-shims.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "@popperjs/core": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "bootstrap": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js"
      }
    }
    </script>
    <script type="module">
      import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'
     
      new bootstrap.Popover(document.getElementById('popoverButton'))
    </script>
```

Кстати, если удалить настройку эту, то ошибки пропадают, но табы перестают работать.

В js у меня

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form = $('#form_buying_product')
    console.log(form);
});
```

И сами ошибки собственно говоря

```
Сценарий из «http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/scripts.js» был загружен, хотя его MIME-тип («text/plain») не является допустимым для JavaScript.
Uncaught TypeError: this._config is undefined
_setListeners tooltip.js:446
Tooltip tooltip.js:123
Popover popover.js:42
<anonymous> 1:126
tooltip.js:446:21
_setListeners tooltip.js:446
Tooltip tooltip.js:123
Popover popover.js:42
<анонимный> 1:126

Object { 0: form#form_buying_product.form-inline, length: 1 }
```

// вроде как не ошибка, как я понял, все таки как-то криво он подгрузился

Comment: А какой смысл подключать одни и те же файлы два раза?

Comment: похоже на то, что вам в настройках нужно явно прописать mimetype для `.js` файлов

Comment: new bootstrap.Popover(document.getElementById('popoverButton')) помогло удаление вот этой строчки, хз почему так